# Convert three 2D numpy arrays to RGB stacked image

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, python-imaging-library, rgb

I have three large 2D arrays of elevation data (5707,5953) each, taken at different baselines. I've normalized the arrays using for example on one:
`normalize = (eledata-np.mean(eledata))/np.std(eledata)`

I've read online and it seems that each data point in my array needs to have a value from 0-255 to be able to assign it an RGB color value based on byte limits. From what I can piece together online I'm a bit stuck here, and have tried this but have been going in loops with different errors. Every other guide I see online has a basic array filled with zeros which is confusing for my large arrays. Here are some different methods I've tried using the PIL, astropy, opencv libraries. I don't have a preference for any, just what will be the simplest to use for this case.

```
normalize[:,:,0] = normalize*64/255.0
normalize[:,:,1] = normalize*128/255.0
normalize[:,:,2] = normalize*192/255.0
cv2.imwrite('C://User/Downloads/color_img.jpg', normalize)
cv2.imshow("image", normalize)
cv2.waitKey()
```

```
def rescale(arr):
     arr_min = arr.min()
     arr_max = arr.max()
     return (arr - arr_min) / (arr_max - arr_min)

red_arr_b = 255.0 * rescale(diff)
green_arr_b = 255.0 * rescale(diff2)
blue_arr_b = 255.0 * rescale(diff3)
```

```
img = Image.fromarray(arr.astype(int), 'RGB')
image = make_lupton_rgb(normalize1,normalize2,normalize3)
plt.show(image)
```

When I have done plot show in the code above, it just returned an empty graph with the x and y range I had set. I have also tried np.dstack, but it didn't seem to give data that made sense and the documentation is short.

```
rgb = np.dstack((normalize1,normalize2,normalize3))
```

What can I try to make the three arrays, one in R, one in G, one in B, and then stack them on top of the other?

***UPDATE***
I've tried to combine both suggested solutions, but right now I'm having an issue as the image is a strange blue color, and even though my limits are set from 0,255, this color seems to take over. The variables diff,diff2,and diff3 are the (5705,5953) arrays I have been talking about. Is it not repetitive to have *255 in both result and im?

```
diff = simslope(data_nan,2,pixsize) - simslope(data_nan,4,pixsize)
diff2 = simslope(data_nan,4,pixsize) - simslope(data_nan,8,pixsize)
diff3 = simslope(data_nan,8,pixsize) - simslope(data_nan,16,pixsize)

normdiff = (diff-np.nanmean(diff))/np.nanstd(diff)
normdiff2 = (diff2-np.nanmean(diff2))/np.nanstd(diff2)
normdiff3 = (diff3-np.nanmean(diff3))/np.nanstd(diff3)
data = (normdiff - np.nanmin(normdiff))/(np.nanmax(normdiff)-np.nanmin(normdiff) + 1e-9)
data2 = (normdiff2 - np.nanmin(normdiff2))/(np.nanmax(normdiff2)-np.nanmin(normdiff2) + 1e-9)
data3 = (normdiff3 - np.nanmin(normdiff3))/(np.nanmax(normdiff3)-np.nanmin(normdiff3) + 1e-9)
result = (255*np.stack((data,data2,data3))).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)
im = Image.fromarray((result[0]*255).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)) 
im.save("C://Users/Downloads/img.png")
plt.imshow(im,vmin=np.nanmin(im),vmax=np.nanmax(im))
```

[image: large plot of elevation data, mostly cyan in color]

Comment: It's not really clear what the issue is. Try making a [mcve] and it should help clarify your thoughts, the issues and potential answers. Maybe click [edit] and declare a height and width that can be modified. Then use those to create 3 channels with `np.random.seed(2023)` or similar and `np.random.xxx()` with appropriate range, dtype, mean, stddev. Then try stacking them and showing what's wrong.

Comment: your newest edit: blame matplotlib, check their docs for what a "colormap" is. and don't expect matplotlib to be nice about handling PIL Images. it's made for numpy arrays.

Answer (score 0):

It's too important how you preprocess your data before converting it to image. In the code I provided I generated fake data and scale it to the range `[0, 255]`

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
data = np.random.randn(5707, 5953, 3)
data = 255*(data - data.min())/(data.max()-data.min() + 1e-9)
data = np.clip(data, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
img = Image.fromarray(data)
img.save("img.png")
plt.imshow(img)
```

Note if there are outliers values, the previous code will give dark images as most values will be close to zero. So as I said, it's important to preprocess your data first, for example keep data in the quantiles `[q5, q95]`

Comment: Does your answer account for outliers? If your solution is to preprocess and only use data in a certain range, does your answer do that?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Please reread the answer. My answer is how to convert data into image, not how to preprocess them. As I am scaling data, outliers will have huge effect, and how to deal with them is data-related.

Comment: when I did this with one of my arrays, it resulted in a grayscale image and showed the elevation that looks correct. Am I to repeat this for the other two arrays I have?

Comment: One of the array you mean 2d array? or the 3d array?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I misunderstand the issue/question, but can you not just use Numpy stack and then multiply by 255 and convert to uint8?

```
result = (255*np.stack((normalize1,normalize2,normalize3))).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)
```

Comment: When I try this method, it says "TypeError: Invalid shape (3, 5707, 5953) for image data" so I imagine before I need to create maybe a third dimension to my array? so that way its (5707,5953,3)

Comment: I thought you had 3 single channel images. I do not think you want to make a 3 channel image from three 3 channel images.  What do you your images represent? Normal 3 channel image would be (5707,5953,3). So I don't think you want to combine 3 of those. Perhaps you need to combine them channel by channel in some way. Please clarify your data structure and what you are trying to do.